# radio button and label align in the same line

Tags: html, css

how to make the radio buttona and label of the radio button align in the same line.
i gave margin and padding to the span tag but its mot moving
whats the solution for it

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right" style="">
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"><span>All</span>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"><span>Name<span>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"><span>Vendor No.<span>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"><span>Contact<span>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Address<span>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Phone
    <input class="span2" type="password">
    <input name="Finish" value="Search" class="checkout-button searchButton" type="submit" style="width: 107px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
</form>
```

Comment: Please fix your code first... unclosed tags everywhere

Comment: In addition to fixing your code can you give us the relevant CSS that you have tried?

Comment: Without seeing your stylesheet it is impossible to determine. By default the label will appear on the same line of a radio button unless it is inheriting styles from elsewhere.

Comment: Please describe the alignment you are looking for.

Comment: shouldn't you be using labels in stead of spans? Both for SEO and for UX as they are clickable. I would try that first as i think the twitter bootstrap, i presume you are using, will align them correctly then.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using actual labels... http://jsfiddle.net/uBUhw/

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right">
    <label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> All</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Name</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Vendor No.</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Contact</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Address</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Phone</label>
    <input class="span2" type="password" />
    <input name="Finish" value="Search" class="checkout-button searchButton"
    type="submit" />
</form>
```

With this setup, the radio buttons will all be inline. If you want each radio button on its own line you can do this:

```
.navbar-form label{
    display:block;
}
```